# Show that $\ker(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal if and only if $B$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ two commutative rings with unity $1_A \not= 0_A$ and $1_B \not= 0_B$. Consider $\phi : A \to B$ a ring epimorphism.

Show that if $\ker(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal, $B$ is a field.

I already know that $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal. As $A$ and $B$ two commutative rings with unity, I know that each invertible element can't be a zero divisor. I think I have to use the surjectivity, but I don't know how.

Is anyone could help me at this point?

Comment: You mean $\phi$ is an epimorphic ring homomorphism?

Comment: @walkar A ring epimorphism is a surjective ring homomorphism, so it's fine.

Comment: That's not true, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings. The question is probably refering to surjective ring homomorphism, and then you can use the isomorphism theorem as in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the first fundamental isomorphism theorem $B$ is isomorphic to $A/\ker(\phi)$.  Now let $a\in A$ where $a\not\in\ker(\phi)$.  Then $(a)+\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal properly containing $\ker(\phi)$.  Thus $(a)+\ker(\phi)=A$.  So $\exists$ $b\in A$ and $m\in\ker(\phi)$ such that $1=m+ab$.  Then $\overline b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\overline a$.  Thus every non-zero element in $A/\ker(\phi)$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By Isomorphism theorems we have $A/\ker \phi \cong \text{Im } \phi = B$. Then $B$ is a field if and only if the quotient is a field if and only if $\ker \phi$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

Comment: I was trying to phrase mine as a hint as well, but since it's pretty immediate I ended up writing the whole thing.

Comment: I honestly did not see yours before posting. But you are correct it is really hard to give a hint on this without giving it away.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. If $\ker(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal, then $A/\ker(\phi)$ is a field, and by the first isomorphism theorem, $A/\ker(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $\phi(A)$, its image. But $\phi(A) = B$ since $\phi$ is surjective. So since $A / \ker(\phi)$ is a field, $B$ is a field, too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\text{ker}(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal. Let us demonstrate that $A/\text{ker}(\phi)$ is a field directly. It suffices to take an arbitrary coset $x + \text{ker}(\phi) \neq \text{ker}(\phi)$ and show there exists a coset $b + \text{ker}(\phi)$ such that:

$(x + \text{ker}(\phi))(b + \text{ker}(\phi)) = 1_A + \text{ker}(\phi) = 1_{A/\text{ker}(\phi)}$

Consider the set $xA = \{xa: a \in A\}$. It is clear that the set:

$xA + \text{ker}(\phi) = \{xa + k: a \in A,\ k\in \text{ker}(\phi)\}$ is an ideal of $A$ containing $\text{ker}(\phi)$.

Since $\text{ker}(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal, we must have $xA + \text{ker}(\phi) = A$. In particular, $1_A \in xA + \text{ker}(\phi)$, that is, there exists $b \in A$ and $k \in \text{ker}(\phi)$, such that:

$xb + k = 1_A$.

Thus$(xb + k) + \text{ker}(\phi) = 1_A + \text{ker}(\phi)$ so:

$(x + \text{ker}(\phi))(b + \text{ker}(\phi)) + (k + \text{ker}(\phi)) = 1_A + \text{ker}(\phi)$, and:

$(x + \text{ker}(\phi))(b + \text{ker}(\phi)) = 1_A + \text{ker}(\phi)$, as desired

(since $k + \text{ker}(\phi) = 0 + \text{ker}(\phi) = \text{ker}(\phi)$ since $k \in \text{ker}(\phi)$).

Now you may apply the isomorphism theorem which says $B \cong A/\text{ker}(\phi)$ to obtain that $B$ is a field.